# Teradata string search product join optimization

Tags: query-optimization, teradata, sql-tuning, teradata-sql-assistant

I have 2 tables.

TableA -> contains Address (2,00,00,000 rows).
TableB -> contains standard pincodes (50,000 rows).

Objective is to derive standard pincodes for each address by searching each pincode in each address string.

```
Select A.ID, A.Address, B.Pincode
From TableA as A
Left join TableB as B
On A.Address like '℅'|| B.Pincode || '℅';
```

This is a product join of 2,00,00,000 X 50,000 records.
And it is taking very long time to execute.

I have also tried alternatives like

```
Select A.ID, A.Address, B.Pincode
From TableA as A
Left join TableB as B
On Position(B.Pincode in A. Address) > 0;
```

```
Select A.ID, A.Address, B.Pincode
From TableA as A
Left join TableB as B
On INSTR(A.Address, B.Pincode ) > 0;
```

In TableA, Address is primary index.
In TableB, Pincode is primary index.
Pincode data is Alphanumeric.
Address data is also Alphanumeric.

But still the execution takes a long time. Almost more than 30mins.

Please help me to optimize this query. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How do the pincodes look like? You might extract them using RegExp_Substr before joining. Is there always a single matching pincode?

Comment: Pincodes example:-   US 123456.  And there might be multiple matching instances, if then those pin codes are not considered.

Comment: Indian pincode? `regexp_substr(x, '[1-9][0-9]{2}\s?[0-9]{3}')` extracts a 6-digit number not staring with 0 and an optional space between digit 3 and 4. Check if the result matches the pincode from your query.